# WPF ReactiveUI Bind Button on ControlTemplate to a ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, reactiveui

Using ReactiveUI I want to bind a button on a ControlTemplate to a simple Command on my ViewModel

In *MyViewModel.cs* :

```
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> MyBCommand;

        // somewhere in MyViewModel ctor...
        MyBCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
            // TODO some stuff...
        });
```

In *MyView.xaml* :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Button Name="MyBButton" .../>
```

in *MyView.xaml.cs* code behind :

```
        // somewhere in MyView ctor...
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, 
                vm => vm.MyBCommand, 
                v => v.MyBButton)); // <<==== !! not reachable!! problem!!
```

from code behind the `v.MyBButton` cannot be resolved.
How can I bind this button?

based on https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/an-example

Comment: What's the relationship between the ControlTemplate and the view model? You won't be able to bind an element that is defined inside a ControlTemplate in the constructor of the view. You'd better bind to the command in the XAML markup of the template.

Comment: Here am trying to keep it simple. 
Am using DevExpress DataGrid, this datagrid has a Search Panel which is basically a ControlTemplate. The purpose is to add a Button on this Search Panel.  [Search Panel - Data Grid - WPF Controls - DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/11403/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Visual-Elements/Common-Elements/Search-Panel)

Comment: Add the button in the template and bind to the command using the {Binding} markup extension in the XAML then.

Comment: this will work, but this goes against the application code style. we don't use the classic {Binding} method. all binding should be done as shown above using `BindCommand(...)`. see [ReactiveUI Data Binding](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/)

Comment: Your "code style" shouldn't inlclude binding to view models in control templates then. A template is a template. There is no button to apply the binding to until the template has been applied to an actual element.

Comment: thanks @mm8 you confirm my assumption, I get your point and I hope you get mine.

Comment: Do you want me to write an answer?

Comment: If I have to bypass that limitation, as I am sometimes in that situation too, I create a seperate sub-view for the Template. In that sub-view I can apply the usual RxUI binding style...

Comment: @MichaelKreich this can be a solution for some use cases, can you give us an example.

Comment: @mm8, your remark was helpful for our team, "_ shouldn't inlclude binding to view models in control templates then _" this is why, the idea to separate sub-view by Michael Kreich can be a solution.

Comment: I built a small example here: https://github.com/jasonwurzel/subview-example sorry, don't have time to write a full blown answer right now